# In which form the org.hibernate.Query returns the result upon calling the list method?

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures

My Java code is ,

```
Query q=session.createSQLQuery(" { call procedureSample(?) }");

List list=q.list();
```

The procedure `procedureSample` returns three values, like (int,string,int).

1. How can I get the results?
2. Whether I need to create the bean? If so, how can I name the fields in the bean, as the int results in my procedure are functions like count?
3. How can I retrieve the results from the list `list` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd get is a `List<Object[]>`, i.e. a list of rows, each represented as an object array.

How the procedure results are accessed depends on whether the results are returned as one row with 3 columns (in this case you'd access the 3rd element as `list.get(0)[2]`) or as 3 rows with one column (accessing the 3rd element would then be `list.get(2)[0]`).

Edit: Note that this assumes you have Java 5+ and cast `list` to `List<Object[]>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your list will contain 3 items. You can iterate through the list and get the values.

For example.

```
Query q=session.createSQLQuery(" { call procedureSample(?) }");

List list=q.list();

Iterator iter=list.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```

No need of creating bean in this case I guess.